# Windows service facing issues after installing on virtual machine

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, service

I have created one windows service in vs2010 and also created two installers.one for 64 bit machine and one for 32 bit machine.It is working fine in development environment.But When I installed on 64 bit virtual machine that time it will give problems.When I install on 32 bit virtual machine,here it is working fine.
Even I tried in 64 bit physical machine,here also it is working fine.
I am getting error like

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at IIVantagesrv.IIV_commonfunctions.ExecQueryCmd(DataSet ds, String Table, String CmdString)select 9 as cnt,
isnull(pth_ptdob,'') as pth_ptdob, isnull(barcode1,'') as barcode1,    isnull(specimen,'') as specimen, isnull(line2,'') as line2,
isnull(orderlist,'') as orderlist, isnull(pth_alpha,'') as mnumber,
isnull(pthspec_tissuetype, '') as tissuetype
from iiv_holdforlabel_iivlabel
inner join iiv_path on specimen = pth_spec
inner join iiv_pathspectype on pth_key = pthspec_key and pthspec_ordernumber = orderlist"
```

I have created "mstr_ds" as a dataset and "reprint" is a datatable on that.here "reprint is datatable name"

```
If mstr_ds.Tables("reprint") Is Nothing = False Then
            mstr_ds.Tables.Remove("reprint")
        End If

Dim str1 As String = "select 9 as cnt, isnull(pth_ptdob,'') as pth_ptdob, isnull(barcode1,'') as barcode1, isnull(specimen,'') as specimen, isnull(line2,'') as line2, isnull(orderlist,'') as orderlist, isnull(pth_alpha,'') as mnumber, isnull(pthspec_tissuetype, '') as tissuetype  from iiv_holdforlabel_iivlabel inner join iiv_path on specimen = pth_spec inner join iiv_pathspectype on pth_key = pthspec_key and pthspec_ordernumber = orderlist"

        ExecQueryCmd(mstr_ds, "reprint", str1)


If mstr_ds.Tables("reprint") Is System.DBNull.Value = False AndAlso mstr_ds.Tables("reprint") Is Nothing = False AndAlso mstr_ds.Tables("reprint").Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso mstr_ds.Tables("reprint").Columns.Count > 3 Then
```

'here some code

one more error is

```
System.ArgumentException: Column 'expr1' does not belong to table hl7spec_cnt.
   at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
   at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)
   at IIVantagesrv.IIV_HL7toVantage.sendtoHL7(String[] specarray, Int32 specarraylength, String hpath)
```

Even if column 'expr1' exists in data table it still gives error.
Here I have found one interesting thing that it is not working properly on windows server 2008.It is working fine in windows 7.
Any one please help me out.Most of the issues what i am getting is related to connection.
" Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state is connecting."
and one more is:

```
  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldType(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetFieldType(Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.SetupSchemaWithoutKeyInfo(MissingMappingAction mappingAction, MissingSchemaAction schemaAction, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object chapterValue)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping..ctor(DataAdapter adapter, DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Boolean keyInfo, SchemaType schemaType, String sourceTableName, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMappingInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMapping(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at IIVantagesrv.IIV_commonfunctions.FillDataSetFromReader(DataSet ds, String table, IDataReader dr)
   at IIVantagesrv.IIV_commonfunctions.ExecQueryCmd(DataSet ds, String Table, String CmdString)select 'sent' as expr1 from iiv_SentHL7 where senthl7_speckey = 2
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. it's not clear exactly what you are doing that is causing the error, and what the code here represents. you talk about installers, then about datasets and reprinting datatables... and somethig about 64 vs 32 bt installers?

Why don't you start at the beginning, and tell us the whole story - don't leave anything out, and please add any and all relevant code (not all your code, all the code that is relevant). Don't reply in the comments - edit your question and add everything in there. Then we can *begin8 to help you figure it out :)

Comment: I got the solution to this..Sorry to inform.Here I am giving the solution.

Comment: It is a windows service and while one process is happening,before completing timer will run once again and it will start to execute from the start.and in my code connection was declared as public.Before executing any db related operation first it will close any open connection and then try to open the connection,but here  if any process is already running then if we try to close the connection,it will start to give the error.So i made connection as private and some of the dataset  also private.so it solved my problem